# What is on topic and what not?

Tags: discussion

I'm a bit perplexed here. Last night I answered the following question: [Use a higher than 230px logo image with 2013 theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144163/use-a-higher-than-230px-logo-image-with-2013-theme/144190#144190). I was surprised this morning to see that the question was put on hold due to be off topic.

This took me back to this question: [Extending content width with twentyfourteen theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144002/extending-content-width-with-twentyfourteen-theme). I raised a flag for this question as off topic, and I even told the OP that CSS related questions are off topic. My flag was declined, and this is what @toscho told me in a comment to my comment left

> It is not off-topic just because it is about CSS. Questions which
>   require knowledge about core internals (like the structure of a core
>   theme) are on-topic.

So, now my question is, the question I've answered about the twenty thirteen header, it is not **" like the structure of a core theme"** and **"require knowledge about core internals"**? This wasn't just a purely CSS question, because you have to change the custom header's function to achieve the proper resize as I stated in my answer. What makes this question to be more off topic that the twentyfourteen question which is purely CSS related. Frankly, I have recently did the exact same thing that the OP was asking, so I know it is just CSS involved.

I don't mind loosing the reputation when the question eventually gets closed, it is just a matter of consistency here. Either the twenty fouteen question must be closed, or the twenty thirteen question must be reopened

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I concur that it is on topic and have agreed with re-open vote.

As for explanation — this isn't exact science. :) Otherwise we would had perfectly fair and impartial bot doing the closing.

I can tell for myself that there are *a lot* of questions passing before my eyes and there are plenty cases when I misunderstand or misjudge in-scope decisions (with or without taking binding moderator action on it).

That's why SE is not just moderated, it's **community moderated**. As a community we are empowered not only to make such decisions, but also question, nitpick, and reverse them for best possible outcome. :)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation and for reopening the question. +1